Pnemautic lift cabinet door won't stay open
I have a cabinet door that refuses to stay open, how/what can I do to fix it? Image below



How old is it? Air struts do wear out.

I meant it won't stay open, whoops

Can try searching for them(unless you have the installation instructions still) and see if there is an adjustment you can try.  My screen door closer has a screw to tighten/loosen movement.

Whatever you do, don't open or heat the struts!  Jokes aside, they look pretty old going by the amount of gunk on the shaft by the pivot.

@Huesmann the gunk makes me wonder: are these air-springs, or are they oil-based dampers?

There seem to be visible part numbers, but they are a bit blurry in the photo.  You should be able to use the part number to find a replacement; if none is available the force number (looks like 100N in the picture) may help you find an alternative of the correct strength.

@MarkMorganLloyd it's possible they're both.  Plenty of gas struts incorporate damping otherwise they'd be too strong (i.e. move too fast) when fully compressed and/or be too weak when nearly fully extended

Google "Domicile Pnemautic hinge". A whole lot of choices will pop up, some at your local home stores. Look for the 100N. Do not try to fix them or take them apart, not worth the risk for the inexpensive price. Once the seals go, they're done for.

For future googlers, 100N is clearly visible in this picture. Go for an exact replacement, 100N is not done magic value. I went for one that was slightly heavier and broke a ball hinge.

Replace it.
It is called a gas spring.
Gas springs are available in many sizes and lift capacities.
Search the internet for the part number that is printed on the part.
